# Swift: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, swift2, exc-bad-instruction

When I attempt this in Playground:

```
func StockEvolution(S_0:Double, _ down:Double, _ up:Double, _ totalsteps:Int, _ upsteps:Int) -> Double // function being used in calcCall()
{
    var S_t:Double = S_0 * pow(up, Double(upsteps)) * pow(down, Double(totalsteps - upsteps))
    return S_t 
}

func CallPayoff(S:Double, _ K:Double) -> Double // function being used in calcCall()
{
    return max(S - K, 0.0)
}

func calcCall(S_0:Double, _ down:Double, _ up:Double, _ r:Double, _ steps:Int, _ K:Double) -> Double //calculate Call-Option
{
    var prices = [Double]()
    var q = 0.6 //risk-neutral probability factor

var i = 0
while i < steps
{
    var payOff = CallPayoff(StockEvolution(S_0, down, up, steps, i), K)
    prices.append(payOff)
    i += 1
}

var n = steps - 1
while n >= 0
{
    var j = 0
    while j <= n
    {
        var value = (1 / r) * (prices[j + 1] * q + (1 - q) * prices[j])
        prices.removeAtIndex(j)
        prices.insert(value, atIndex: j)
        j += 1
    }
    n -= 1
}
return prices[0]
}
```

By doing this:

```
var checkPrice = calcCall(100, 0.6, 1.5, 1.05, 10, 200)
```

It gives me this error:

Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

I can't seem to find the bug in my code. I've tried with different input values but the error still occurs.

It would be great if you could have a look at my code and help me to fix this issue. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your nested `while` loops. The first time you loop through, `n` is set to `9`, which means that on the final pass through the nested loop you end up with `j == 9`, which clearly means `j + 1 == 10`. But you're trying to get `prices[j + 1] == prices[10]`, which doesn't exist. Hence the crash.

To see this, add the following if statement:

```
if j + 1 < prices.count {
    let value = (1 / r) * (prices[j + 1] * q + (1 - q) * prices[j])
    prices.removeAtIndex(j)
    prices.insert(value, atIndex: j)
}
j += 1
```

You'll no longer get the bad access error.

Now, I don't know the problem domain at all, so I can't say *why* your algorithm was incorrect. As such the answer I've provided may not give you the values you expect. You'll probably have to work out why you're trying to access a non-existent index, and how to work around that.

Finally, if I may, some general style points:

- You  might noticed I swapped the `var` in the code sample above for a `let`. Since `value` is never mutated (instead being redefined at each pass through the loop) it doesn't need to be mutable. Removing mutable state will make it easier to find problems in your code.
- You've used a lot of while loops with mutable state to track progress through them. These can all be replaced with `for...in` loops. E.g. the first while can be replaced with `for i in 0..<steps` without any affecting the code. This again helps cut down on mutable state, and programmer error.

I took the liberty of rewriting your code to make it a bit more "Swifty", while also removing as much mutable state as possible. Here it is:

```
func stockEvolution(s_0: Double, _ down: Double, _ up: Double, _ totalsteps: Int, _ upsteps: Int) -> Double {
    let s_t: Double = s_0 * pow(up,  Double(upsteps)) * pow(down,  Double(totalsteps - upsteps))
    return s_t
}

func callPayoff(s: Double, _ k: Double) -> Double {
    return max(s - k, 0.0)
}

func calcCall(s_0: Double, _ down: Double, _ up: Double, _ r: Double, _ steps:Int, _ k: Double) -> Double {
    var prices = Array(0..<steps).map { step in
        return callPayoff(stockEvolution(s_0, down, up, steps, step), k)
    }
    let q = 0.6 //risk-neutral probability factor

    for n in (0..<steps).reverse() {
        for j in 0...n where j + 1 < prices.count {
            let value = (1 / r) * (prices[j + 1] * q + (1 - q) * prices[j])
            prices.removeAtIndex(j)
            prices.insert(value, atIndex: j)
        }
    }
    return prices[0]
}

let checkPrice = calcCall(100, 0.6, 1.5, 1.05, 10, 200)
```

Comment: Thank you Sir for taking your time to look through my code. That makes sense

Comment: ... The explanation you provided me makes absolutely sense. Yup, I can see now why the error occurs. Unfortunately, the result doesn't  make much sense. I will go through my code. Maybe I made a mistake in the formula or implemented it wrongly. I also appreciate your advices (because I am a novice at Swift). Kind regards.